# Drupal mobile site themes

Tags: drupal, mobile, themes, drupal-theming

I'm developing mobile part of website and I need recommendation for a module and themes.

As far as modules concerned - Which one do you use - http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools or http://drupal.org/project/mobileplugin?

I'd also like you to recommend me some of Mobile Themes for Drupal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be the best writeup on the subject with all kinds of help, it's in four parts:

[Mobile Drupal (part 1): The groundwork](http://cruncht.com/417/mobile-drupal-groundwork)

[Mobile Drupal (part 2): Site setup](http://cruncht.com/419/mobile-drupal-site-setup)

[Mobile Drupal (part 3): The code](http://cruncht.com/421/mobile-drupal-code)

[Mobile Drupal (part 4): Conclusions](http://cruncht.com/423/mobile-drupal-conclusions)

Answer (score 1):

create a Drupal mobile site without using Mobile Tools

Modules:

http://drupal.org/project/mobilekey
http://drupal.org/project/themekey

Explanation:

http://www.digett.com/blog/08/18/2011/drupal-mobile-how-create-drupal-mobile-site-without-using-mobile-tools

Answer (score 0):

If your working in D6, I would suggest starting with BrowseCap http://drupal.org/project/browscap, it integrates with a couple different modules, but is also fairly easy to use on its own.

As for mobile themes, good luck. I haven't found one out-of-box that was even a good starting point. I noticed development of the more popular ones has really dropped off. I think most people are doing what I have been doing myself. Start by looking at the really excellent WordPress mobile theme, and roll your own.